# How do I automate the timing of a sound effect to a list of exact times?

Tags: software, sound, synthesizer, synthesis, sequencer

I have an effect I have to make where two sounds alternate, starting with large pauses between them, and then get faster and faster until they alternate on a sample-basis. I am using the roots of sin(x(-24/(24-x))), xe[0,24) to model when I want these sounds to play. I wrote a program that generates a list of timestamps (in samples) to simulate this (eventually a sound should play for each sample, 48000 times per second let's say, generating a pure frequency).

How should I go about turning this list of times into a sound effect? Or in other words, how can I automate this so that it is mathematically exact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you are a programmer, why not find an audio library that allows you to read and write audio files, and just write another bit of your program that renders the sound you want to a new audio file?

Comment: For this kind of stuff you might want to look into SuperCollider or PureData. It's trivial to do stuff like that in those (or similar) synthesis environments that already provide you with both sound synthesis engines and a programming language. SuperCollider is based on C-like syntax, so programmers can normally jump right into it. Both are free and open source.

Comment: Agreed with Huffman, I can do this in a couple minutes with MAX

Comment: That's awesome. I'll give that a go, thanks a ton.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - Turn your mention of using MAX for that purpose into an answer, then.